# decode binary from xmlrpc python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I'm new to python and xml-rpc , and I'm stuck with decoding binary data coming from a public service :

the service request response with this code is :

```
from xmlrpc.client import Server

import xmlrpc.client  

from pprint import pprint

DEV_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

logFile = open('stat.txt', 'w')

s1 = Server('http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/autenticazione/1')
s2 = Server('http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/paline/7')

token = s1.autenticazione.Accedi(DEV_KEY, '')

res = s2.paline.GetStatPassaggi(token)

pprint(res, logFile)
```

response :

```
{'id_richiesta': '257a369dbf46e41ba275f8c821c7e1e0',
 'risposta': {'periodi_aggregazione': <xmlrpc.client.Binary object at 0x0000027B7D6E2588>,
              'tempi_attesa_percorsi': <xmlrpc.client.Binary object at 0x0000027B7D9276D8>}}
```

I need to decode these two binary objects , and I'm stuck with this code :

```
from xmlrpc.client import Server

import xmlrpc.client  

from pprint import pprint

DEV_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

logFile = open('stat.txt', 'w')

s1 = Server('http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/autenticazione/1')
s2 = Server('http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/paline/7')

token = s1.autenticazione.Accedi(DEV_KEY, '')

res = s2.paline.GetStatPassaggi(token)

dat = xmlrpc.client.Binary(res)
out = xmlrpc.client.Binary.decode(dat)

pprint(out, logFile)
```

that ends in :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "stat.py", line 18, in
>   
>       dat = xmlrpc.client.Binary(res)   File "C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\xmlrpc\client.py",
>   line 389, in **init**
>       data.**class**.**name**) TypeError: expected bytes or bytearray, not dict

The only doc I found for xmlrpc.client is the one at docs.python.org , but I can't figure out how I could decode these binaries

Comment: It seems like you are doing the correct call, maybe the problem is on the website? ´TypeError: expected bytes or bytearray, not dict´ ? I would think that you are actually receiving a ´dict´ instead of a ´bytearray´

Comment: yes , I think it's a dict. I'll try to contact website developer

Answer (score 0):

If the content of ***res*** variable (what you get from the 2<sup>nd</sup> (*s2*) server) is the response you pasted into the question, then you should modify the last 3 lines of your 2<sup>nd</sup> snippet to (as you already have 2 *Binary* objects in the *res* dictionary):

```py
# ... Existing code
res = s2.paline.GetStatPassaggi(token)

answer = res.get("risposta", dict())
aggregation_periods = answer.get("periodi_aggregazione", xmlrpc.client.Binary())
timeout_paths = answer.get("tempi_attesa_percorsi", xmlrpc.client.Binary())

print(aggregation_periods.data)
print(timeout_paths.data)
```

**Notes**:

- According to [[Python.Docs]: xmlrpc.client - Binary Objects](https://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpc.client.html#binary-objects) (**emphasis** is mine):

> [Binary](https://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpc.client.html#xmlrpc.client.Binary) objects have the following methods, supported **mainly for internal use** by the marshalling/unmarshalling code:

- I wasn't able to connect (and this test the solution), since ***DEV_KEY*** is (obviously) fake